# How to create HQL query using fields from extended class

Tags: java, sql, spring, kotlin, hql

I have those both classes: Locatable and Device such that Locatable Extends Device:
**Locatable:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Locatable.TABLE_NAME)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "device_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
open class Locatable: Device() {

@Basic
@Column(name = NAME_COLUMN)
var name: String? = null
 }
```

**Device:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Device.TABLE_NAME)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Device {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGen")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGen", sequenceName = "devices_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
 @Column(name = ID_COLUMN)
 open var id: Long = 0

 @Basic
 @Column(name = GROUP_COLUMN)
 open var groupId: Long = 0
 }
```

as you can see **groupId** field exist **only in Device**
Now, I want to get do this repo:

```
  interface LocatableRepo : JpaRepository<Locatable, Long> {
   @Query("SELECT l FROM Locatable l  WHERE l.groupId IN ?1")
   fun getByGroupIdIn(ids: List<Long>): List<Locatable>

   }
```

My question is if I do it right or should I use **left join fetch**?
because groupId isn't in Locatable it means that it isn't in **l** so how can I use **l.groupId**?(Is that because the extending to Device?)

Thank you

Comment: anyone has an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your class Locatable is extending Device and so also extends the columns of the super class. Your query should be correct.

I am using such queries quiet often in my Java code and have no problems so far.